# How to display <li> items from top to bottom not from left to right?

Tags: html, html-lists

I have a list items which I am mapping on `<ul>` `<li>`.

```
<ul>
<li>Item1</li>
<li>Item2</li>
<li>Item3</li>
<li>Item4</li>
<li>Item5</li>
<li>Item6</li>
<li>Item7</li>
<li>Item8</li>
<li>Item9</li>
<li>Item10</li>
<li>Item11</li>
</ul>
```

It display the items on the page like from left to right:

```
Item1 Item2 Item3 Item4 Item5
Item6 Item7 Item8 Item9 Item10
Item11
```

I want to display them from top to bottom like

```
Item1 Item4 Item7 Item10
Item2 Item5 Item8 Item11
Item3 Item6 Item9
```

How can I display them from top to bottom?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Wrapping lists into columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4923/wrapping-lists-into-columns)

Comment: Will the <li> tags br hard-coded or generated dynamically?

Comment: Are you using any server language like PHP ? If so, I can give you good answer !

Comment: i am using c# and backend is in mvc view.

Comment: <li> is generating hard coded like  
foreach(var item in list) {

<li>item.Name</li>
}

Comment: @ravi i am using c# and backend is in mvc view

Comment: While I don't have time to explore it right now, part of me is feeling that this might be possible with some floats or something in CSS..

Comment: @joesavage float:left is set in css and width is set to 850px

Answer (score 0):

```
int count = 0;
<ul style="display:inline" >
    if(count < items.length)
    {
        print("<li>");
        print("<ul>");
        for(int a = 1 ; count < items.length && a <= 3 , count++ , a++)
        {
               print("<li>" + items[count].Name + "</li>");
        }
        print("</ul>");
        print("</li>");
    }
</ul>
```

May this pseudocode help you.

Answer (score 0):

you could do this with just HTML and some simple CSS, but you'd have to make separate lists for each set of items you wanted separted by column:

```
<style>
ul {
    margin-top:0px;
    margin-left:0px;
    float:left;
}

</style>

<html>
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>Item 4</li>
  <li>Item 5</li>
  <li>Item 6</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>Item 7</li>
  <li>Item 8</li>
  <li>Item 9</li>
</ul>
</html>
```

Comment: no <li> is generating in a for loop on the basis of list length,so can't seperate it in different <ul>.

Comment: no, but you could tell it to make divs every "nth" iteration, and then just set the same css properties for the divs

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have to support IE < 10 use CSS3 columns:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS3_Columns